# Date formatting with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using Python 2.6.2
Matplotlib 1.1.0

Based on http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/date_index_formatter.html, 
I have built a Python program to generate an image plot

```
gr = getResults()
AttributeName = gr.getAttributeName(attributeId)
dates = []
values = []
for data in gr.byClient(clientId, attributeId):
    dates.append(data[0])
    values.append(data[1])

from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

# Create a figure with size 6 x 6 inches.
fig = Figure(figsize=(6,6))

# Create a canvas and add the figure to it.
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)

# Create a subplot.
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Set the title.
ax.set_title("Response over time",fontsize=14)

# Set the X Axis label.
ax.set_xlabel("Date",fontsize=12)

# Set the Y Axis label.
ax.set_ylabel(AttributeName,fontsize=12)

# Display Grid.
ax.grid(True,linestyle='-',color='0.75')

N = len(dates)
ind = np.arange(N)

def format_date(x, pos=None):
    thisind = np.clip(int(x+0.5),0, N-1)
    return dates[thisind].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(format_date))

# Generate the Scatter Plot.
ax.scatter(dates,values,s=20,color='tomato');
fig.autofmt_xdate()

# Save the generated Scatter Plot to a PNG file.
canvas.print_figure(outputFileName,dpi=50)
```

The problem is in the format_date method. When it is called the x parameter has values like 734586, 734747, 734808 ... This causes the clip method to always set the index to the last date. The actual layout of the final image is ok, it is just selecting the wrong date. How is the x value to be used to select evenly spaced dates?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call pylab.num2date() to convert this numbers into datetime object:

```
import pylab as pl
from matplotlib import ticker
from datetime import date

dates = [date(2012,7,10), date(2012,8,5), date(2012,9,4)]
values = [1,2,3]

def format_date(x, pos=None):
    return pl.num2date(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(format_date))

# Generate the Scatter Plot.
scatter(dates,values,s=20,color='tomato');
gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

[image]