# Using datetime in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I have an amount of times written in the format hh:mm:ss, if I use the code below and print what x is I get 1900, 1, 1, 10, 29, 34 for every timestamp. How can I take away the year, month and date? As I want to have the time in the format hh:mm:ss

EDIT: Updated with the whole code as it looks now with help from comments.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker
import time
import datetime

x = ['10:29:55', '10:34:44']           
sy1 = [679.162, 679.802]

x_labels = [datetime.datetime.strptime(elem, '%H:%M:%S') for elem in x]
formatter = matplotlib.ticker. FixedFormatter(x_labels)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_formatter(formatter)

plt.plot(x_labels, sy1, 'ro')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Position')
plt.show()
```

But obviously it displays the time when taking into account the year, month and date too.

[Plotting (wrong) time against y values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7QZw.png)

If I use strftime instead of strptime I get a TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'

Comment: So, is the issue with parsing datetimes, or with the plot? Separate those two things and tackle them independently.

Comment: try `plt.plot(x,y)`. x and y are already lists, and matplotlib doesn't need a 2d list in this case.

Comment: Your edits have taken away the reference to an image.  Are you trying to plot using matplotlib?  You probably want https://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.autofmt_xdate.  If you could edit what plot library you're using, you may get people willing to answer.

Comment: If your question gets re-opened, I'll post an answer, but for now try `plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()`.  This will get the current figure and set autofmt_xdate, which should make the date as neat as possible (including removing the date when it's constant and only showing the time).

Comment: I have allready tried the plt.gfc()autofmt_xdate(), it only tilts the numbers, makes it more neater.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  There are a few ways to get what you want.

If you're willing to settle for having microseconds, you should be really close to what you need:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

time_strings = ['10:29:55', '10:34:44']           
sy1 = [679.162, 679.802]

times = [datetime.datetime.strptime(elem, '%H:%M:%S') for elem in time_strings]
plt.plot(times, sy1, 'ro')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Position')
plt.show()
```

This should show the times you want in a plot, just with microseconds in the formatting.  The microseconds make it all ugly, but my only changes were ones for clarity - I didn't `import time` or `import matplotlib.ticker`, I changed your `x` to a more accurate variable name, and created the datetimes as you did.  To get rid of the microseconds, things get uglier.  You can't just use the FixedFormatter because we only set 2 values, and the standard plot has more than 2 ticks; you have to find a way to get the FuncFormatter to work.  This works as desired, but is still too noisy, so I'm adding in the `plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()` as well.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker
import datetime
import pylab

time_strings = ['10:29:55', '10:34:44']           
sy1 = [679.162, 679.802]

times = [datetime.datetime.strptime(elem, '%H:%M:%S') for elem in time_strings]
plt.plot(times, sy1, 'ro')
formatter = matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda tick_value, _: datetime.datetime.strftime(pylab.num2date(tick_value), '%H:%M:%S'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_formatter(formatter)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Position')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

The line defining the FuncFormatter is messy.  I define a lambda, which is a function defined on a single line.  FuncFormatter expects it to take 2 arguments.  The first one is the tick_value, and we don't really care what the second one is, so I gave it the standard variable name of `_` to show we don't care.  The tick values are datetimes or timestamps.  The way we get from the tick value to a datetime is by calling pylab.num2date.

You'll find that this second solution is just what you need.  The key thing you needed to do was keep track of what your variable types were, and what variable types were needed where.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean plt.gca() ? Unfortunately I get a plot where the values in the x comes out like 1900-01-01 10:29:34, so I still need to get rid of those year/month/date stamp. I borrowed your last code by the way, I didn't want to totally changed my old one :)

Comment: I updated with the whole code, and as I wrote in my first post (just now) I get a TypeError if I use strftime. Sorry, I'm seriously a newbie on this.

Comment: Thanks for adding all your code.  :-)  In the future, please do this from the start.  I'll rewrite my answer to reflect what you've now told us.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623498/date-formatting-with-matplotlib, which I used in coming up with my answer.  Your question at this point is a good one, but it would've been a lot easier (and you would've gotten your answer faster by someone more skilled than I, I bet), if you had simply started by posting all your code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems to work now, I will research more about the way you used the code so I understand it completely. And I will remember to include my whole code right away next time :)

Comment: You're welcome.  Feel free to ask any questions if you need clarification to my answer.  Also, at some time, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers to see suggestions of what you should do once a question is answered.